# Send email with Sendblue API and TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to send an e-mail by sendblue api.

Using Postman app I can send the e-mail using something as:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 497' \
  -H 'Cookie: __cfduid=d49b2d4eb12e019d10adc31e48c2682001573229677' \
  -H 'Host: api.sendinblue.com' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 79980bf9-b0f5-442d-a93e-0835ef471bac,6653fb5c-29da-4a00-83bc-cecb1c70b0bb' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'api-key: xkeysib-728f8759d3fdbasdasdasdasd5asdsq083a48387459eba9cc57f9ad7904e-dqLADTR6vxw4y3GQ' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{  
   "sender":{  
      "name":"Sender Alex",
      "email":"gestaaloud@outlook.com"
   },
   "to":[  
      {  
         "email":"cprmlasasaao@gmail.com",
         "name":"John Doe"
      }
   ],
   "subject":"test mail",
   "htmlContent":"<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello this is a test email from sib</h1></body></html>",
   "headers":{  
      "X-Mailin-custom":"custom_header_1:custom_value_1|custom_header_2:custom_value_2|custom_header_3:custom_value_3",
      "charset":"iso-8859-1"
   }
}'
```

I did the next function to send the email using delphi 10.3 with indy, but I am getting a 404 error. What am I doing wrong?

```
procedure Test_Email();
var  fIdHTTP : TIdHTTP;
     hdlSocket:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
     RequestUTF8 : TStringStream;
     js,jso : TJSONobject;
     ja :TJsonArray;
     function GetJsonMail: String;
      begin
      js := TJSONobject.Create;
      try
         jso:= TJSONobject.Create;
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('name'  , 'Gestan'));
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('email'  , 'gestancsadfasd@outlook.com'));
         js.AddPair('sender',jso);

         ja := TJSONArray.Create;
         jso:= TJSONobject.Create;
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('email'  , 'cprmlasdaao@gmail.com'));
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('name'  , 'Luiz'));
         ja.AddElement(jso);
         js.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('to'  , ja));


         js.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('subject'  , 'Teste email'));
         js.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('htmlContent'  , '<b>Teste email</b>'));

         jso:= TJSONobject.Create;
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('X-Mailin-custom'  , 'custom_header_1:custom_value_1|custom_header_2:custom_value_2|custom_header_3:custom_value_3'));
         jso.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('charset'  , 'iso-8859-1'));
         js.AddPair(TJSONPair.Create('headers'  , jso));
         result:=js.ToJSON;
      finally
          js.Free;
      end;
   end;
begin
  fIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  with fIdHTTP do
  begin
    Request.Clear;
    Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('api-key',API_KEY_BLUE);
    Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    Request.CharSet := 'iso-8859-1';
    HTTPOptions := [];
    Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    HandleRedirects := true;
    hdlSocket:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
    with hdlSocket do
    begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
      SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
    end;
    IOHandler := hdlSocket;
  end;

  RequestUTF8 := TStringStream.Create(GetJsonMail,TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    fIdHTTP.Post('https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/email', RequestUTF8);
  finally
    RequestUTF8.Free;
    fIdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that the JSON output you create in Delphi matches the JSON you're sending with curl. For instance, the curl contains a `Sender` entry, while the Dephi JSON does not. Have you compared that generated JSON carefully with the information sent via curl? It appears to me that the requests are considerably different. Also, your curl code sends to a different URL (the curl version uses `v3/smtp/email`, the Delphi version uses `v3/email`).

Comment: Actually, the more I look at the content of the two examples, the more differences I find. If you're sending two mostly different requests, it's not surprising that the new one fails to work. You may want to revisit the content you're attempting to send.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP response code 404 means you are posting to a URL that does not exist. Look at the URLs being used by the curl and `TIdHTTP` calls. They are different URLs. The curl code is posting to this URL:

> https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email

But your `TIdHTTP` code is posting to this URL instead:

> https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/email

See the difference?

Your `TIdHTTP` code is also not setting up all of the same HTTP headers as the curl code. In particular, the 'Postman-Token' and 'Cookie' headers are missing.

Try this:

```pascal
procedure Test_Email();
var
  fIdHTTP : TIdHTTP;
  hdlSocket : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  RequestUTF8 : TStringStream;

  function GetJsonMail: String;
  var
    js, jso : TJSONObject;
    ja : TJSONArray;
  begin
    js := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      jso := TJSONObject.Create;
      try
        jso.AddPair('name', 'Gestan');
        jso.AddPair('email', 'gestancsadfasd@outlook.com');
        js.AddPair('sender', jso);
      except
        jso.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      ja := TJSONArray.Create;
      try
        jso := TJSONObject.Create;
        try
          jso.AddPair('email', 'cprmlasdaao@gmail.com');
          jso.AddPair('name', 'Luiz');
          ja.AddElement(jso);
        except
          jso.Free;
          raise;
        end;
        js.AddPair('to', ja);
      except
        ja.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      js.AddPair('subject', 'Teste email');
      js.AddPair('htmlContent', '<b>Teste email</b>');
      jso := TJSONObject.Create;
      try
        jso.AddPair('X-Mailin-custom', 'custom_header_1:custom_value_1|custom_header_2:custom_value_2|custom_header_3:custom_value_3');
        jso.AddPair('charset', 'iso-8859-1');
        js.AddPair('headers', jso);
      except
        jso.Free;
        raise;
      end;
      Result := js.ToJSON;
    finally
      js.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  fIdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    fIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('api-key', API_KEY_BLUE);
    fIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Postman-Token', '...');
    fIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Cookie', '__cfduid=...');
    fIdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    fIdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
    fIdHTTP.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
    fIdHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    fIdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    fIdHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];

    hdlSocket := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(fIdHTTP);
    hdlSocket.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1, sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
    hdlSocket.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    hdlSocket.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    hdlSocket.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
    fIdHTTP.IOHandler := hdlSocket;

    RequestUTF8 := TStringStream.Create(GetJsonMail, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      fIdHTTP.Post('https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/smtp/email', RequestUTF8);
    finally
      RequestUTF8.Free;
    end;
  finally
    fIdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```